# resultado em 2 colunas da tabela

Tags: php, mysql, css

Boa tarde amigos, estou com dificuldade em montar uma tabela com resultado em 2 colunas com informações do banco de dados.

```
<table style='width: 100%;' border='1' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0'>

<thead>
    <tr style='background-color: #CCCCCC;'>

        <td style='text-align: center; width: 12.5%; height:20px'><h3>Equipamento locado</h3></td>
        <td style='text-align: center; width: 12.5%;'><h3>Patrimônio</h3></td>

    </tr>

</thead>
<tbody> 


if($cliente->equipamento){

    $array_equipamento = explode( "," , $cliente->equipamento ) ;

    foreach ($array_equipamento as $value) {

    $equipamento = $objeto_equipamento->busca_equipamento($value);


    <tr>

        <td style='text-align: center; width: 12,5%; height:20px'>$equipamento->nome</td>
        <td style='text-align: center; width: 12,5%;'>$equipamento->patrimonio</td>

    </tr>

    }

}


</tbody>
</table> 




    <table>

    <tr><td>coluna 1 </td> <td> Coluna 2 </td> </tr> 



    <tr><td> 1 </td> <td> 2 </td></tr>
    <tr><td> 3 </td> <td> 4 </td></tr>
    <tr><td> 5 </td> <td> 6 </td></tr>
    <tr><td> 7 </td> <td> 8 </td></tr>



    </table>
```

Os números do exemplo representam a sequencia de resultados para melhor entendimento.

Comment: Não estou entendendo... qual código você está usando?

Comment: desculpa, editei o html para melhor vizualização !!!

Comment: Precisamos saber da onde você pega essas informações?

Comment: do banco de dados mysql ... vem da consulta query !!!

Comment: `$equipamento` faz assim da um `var_dump($equipamento)` e cola o resultado aqui!

Comment: è o seguinte, eu ja recebo e listo tudo na tabela amigo, o problema que tenho é montar o resultado em duas colunas, só isso .... um algoritimo para dividir na tabela

Comment: Thiago, meu caro Odson, se você não passar como está as colunas dessa tabela, fica complicado sabermos como gerar a mesma!

Comment: como informei, o importante nao são meus dados e sim como apresentar o resultado dividido em 2 colunas, se vc conseguir o algoritimo eu aplico em meu codigo !!

Comment: é complicado dar um `var_dump`?

Comment: @ThiagoLopez
Somente com os dados fornecidos é impossível propor uma solução.

Comment: editei o codigo, se fica ais simples pra voces assim ! 

Como podem ver esta listando em duas colunas com duas informações, porem eu quero que tenha mais duas colunas a direita e que liste 2 registros por linha para aproveitar o tamanho da folha.

Answer (score 0):

Boas,

Mostra a estrutura da tabela sff.

Simulei a esturra das tabelas com classes utilitário (código a seguir) e resultado foi o apresentado a seguir. Não alterei mais nada.

```
    <?php 

/*
*
* Classes utilitária para simular a estrutura da tabela
*/
class Equipamento{

    public $id;
    public $nome;
    public $patrimonio; 

    public function busca_equipamento($value){

        $testeEquipamentos = self::obterListaDeEquipamenetoTeste();

        foreach($testeEquipamentos as $k => $equipamento){
            if($equipamento->id == $value){
                return $equipamento;
            }
        }

        // um pequeno teste, caso não for encontado o respetivo id/value
        return new  Equipamento();
    }

    public function obterListaDeEquipamenetoTeste(){

        $eq1 = new Equipamento();
        $eq1->id = 1;
        $eq1->nome = "Equipamento 1";
        $eq1->patrimonio = "200€";

        $eq2 = new Equipamento();
        $eq2->id = 2;
        $eq2->nome = "Equipamento 2";
        $eq2->patrimonio = "300€";

        $eq3 = new Equipamento();
        $eq3->id = 3;
        $eq3->nome = "Equipamento 2";
        $eq3->patrimonio = "400€";  

        return [$eq1,$eq2,$eq3];

    }
}

class Cliente{
    public $id;
    public $nome;
    public $equipamento;
}

$cliente = new Cliente();
$cliente->id = '1111';
$cliente->nome = 'Clinet Teste';
$cliente->equipamento = '1,2,3';

?>




    <?php
    /*
    *
    * codigo original => nada alterado
    */
    <table style='width: 100%;' border='1' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0'>

    <thead>
    <tr style='background-color: #CCCCCC;'>

        <td style='text-align: center; width: 12.5%; height:20px'><h3>Equipamento locado</h3></td>
        <td style='text-align: center; width: 12.5%;'><h3>Patrimônio</h3></td>

    </tr>

    </thead>
    <tbody> 

    <?php



    $objeto_equipamento = new Equipamento();

    if($cliente->equipamento){

        $array_equipamento = explode( "," , $cliente->equipamento ) ;

        foreach ($array_equipamento as $value) {

        $equipamento = $objeto_equipamento->busca_equipamento($value);


        echo "<tr>

            <td style='text-align: center; width: 12,5%; height:20px'>$equipamento->nome</td>
            <td style='text-align: center; width: 12,5%;'>$equipamento->patrimonio</td>

        </tr>";

        }

    }

    ?>

    </tbody>
    </table>
```

[image: E o resultado]

Comment: muito bom amigo, agora o que falta é fazer o que realmente preciso que é listar o resultado da maneira que descrevi na pergunta !! sendo 2 registros por linha na tabela.

Comment: Podes postar uma imagem do diagrama da base de dados. Suponho que tens duas tabelas "Cliente" e "Equipamento". Onde cada cliente pode ter 0 ou mais equipamento.

Answer (score 0):

Boa tarde a todos, obrigado pela ajuda de todos mas já resolvi meu problema ... segui o codigo fonte onde separo os resultados da query em duas colunas independente da qtd de registros, grato.

```
if($cliente->equipamento){

    // quantidade de virgulas faz distinção de numero de registros - 1
    // $reg é uma string separada por ',' na coluna $cliente->equipamento na minha BD, para entendimento de todos
    $reg = substr_count( $cliente->equipamento , ',' ) ; 

    $array_equipamento = explode( "," , $cliente->equipamento ) ;

    $colunas = 2;

    $html .= '<tr>';

    $i = 0;

    foreach ($array_equipamento as $value) 
    {

        $equipamento = $objeto_equipamento->busca_equipamento($value);

        if( $i == $colunas)
        {
            $html .= '</tr><tr>';
            $i=0;
        }

        $html .= '<td>'.$equipamento->nome.'</td>';
        $i++;
    }

    $html .= '</tr>';
}
```

Comment: alguem pode aceitar minha resposta para finalizar o top, por favor !!!